# Sending mail in PHP to different e-mails in single button submit

Tags: php, html, forms

For one of my website, I am using a contact form and the PHP code is given below.
If  the details are posted through the HTML form, I am getting the mail "mail@xyz.com".

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    header('Location: error.html');
    exit;
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "mail@xyz.com";
$subject = "Through Contact form";


$email_body = "NAME:     $name\n".
              "PLACE:    $place\n".
              "EMAIL-ID: $email\n\n".
              "Message:  $message\n";

$to = "mail@xyz.com";

//Send the email!
mail($to, $subject, $email_body);


//done
header('Location: thank.html');
?>
```

What I want  is sending the same messgae to differnet mail in single button submit.
Example:

```
mail@xyz.com, 
info@abcd.com,  
contact@othersite.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    header('Location: error.html');
    exit;
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$emails = array("mail@xyz.com", "info@abcd.com" , "contact@othersite.com");

$subject = "Through Contact form";


$email_body = "NAME:     $name\n".
              "PLACE:    $place\n".
              "EMAIL-ID: $email\n\n".
              "Message:  $message\n";

$to = "mail@xyz.com";

//Send the email!

foreach ($emails as $to) {
mail($to, $subject, $email_body);
}

//done
header('Location: thank.html');
```

?>

Comment: Shall we mention: $to = "mail@xyz.com", "info@abcd.com" , "contact@othersite.com" ;

Comment: then you have to edit foreach loop to something like foreach ($to as $toemail) {
mail($toemail, $subject, $email_body);
}

Comment: **Rikesh's** answer is perfect, but then everyone in to field can see other email address.